# Wordpress FB plugin

Tags: authentication, facebook

I am currently trying to make use of a FB login plugin for Wordpress.

In one of the support threads, it mentions the issue I am having is commonly fixed if you:
“Switch the “Encrypted Access Token” setting to ‘Enabled’.”

I don't have this option in the advanced app settings:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35816363/otto.jpg

Can someone please advise what is wrong in my app settings that this option is not available?

Thanks 
Lee

Answer (score 0):

Have you migrated your app to oAuth 2.0? As far as I know, that setting  “Switch the “Encrypted Access Token” setting to ‘Enabled’.” will only appear when you've set your app to oAuth 2.0.

I think you could accept the migration by activating the Open Graph feature in the app settings [-> get started] (if not, I apologize in advance; I did this many moons ago ^^;) On a side note: Activating Open Graph comes with the Timeline preview in your FB profile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I only set up the app 2 days ago so I wouldn't have thought any migration would be needed?  

I tried activation Open Graph and that didn't seem to add the encrypted access token toggle.

Comment: Hmm... the app settings should look like this by then O.O http://homura.sakuraindex.jp/public/fbappsettings.png

Comment: Thanks mate.  I'm really not sure what I have done but I will attempt to set up a new app and prey it works.  I'm not a tech person so this is all very new to me.